# How do I use Emacs as a feedly.com client?

Tags: xml, web

**Q:** How do I use feedly.com as an RSS feed source in Emacs 24.4?

I've searched sporadically for months. I haven't found anything to even point me in the right direction to get started.

I've opened a ticket with Feedly as well.

**Context**

While not required for the question at hand, if you're interested please see my [blog post](http://www.thinknix.net/2014/12/05/how-do-i-use-feedly-com-as-an-rss-feed-source-in-emacs/). It provides additional information as well as my end game.

**Update 2015-02-17**

I updated the title according to the suggestion in the comments. My intent is for Emacs to fill the role Reeder and Readkit perform on OS X as well as on Gnu/Linux and MS Windows, where no analog resides.

Comment: Why 24.4? Do you want to use it with `eww`? For that, what you lack is mainly a javascript engine. Or do you want to use it with any of the existing RSS readers? In that case, it seems that your question is about obtaining a RSS feed from feedly, which is not really related to emacs.

Comment: Side question: what does feedly do that you couldn't do with any RSS reader directly collecting the various feeds which you want to read?

Comment: @T. Verron it is online, so it's easy to use from anywhere. It knows what you have read already, etc. Setting up your own rss server and syncing state across devices is more complicated.

Comment: Feedly has an API. Can't you use it? https://developer.feedly.com/

Comment: IIUC, you'd like to use Emacs as a feedly client. If so, please at those words to the question (or title).

Comment: @T.Verron, I want to use it to sync rss feeds across platforms. If I read an article on one I want it marked as read on all other platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that you can't use Emacs as a Feedly client, or at least not without regenerating a developer key every three months. I received the same information as the folks at [Feednix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/feednix/).

There are two possible alternate solutions, neither of which I've yet tested:

1. Use [rss2email](https://github.com/turbodog/rss2email) and have it send the articles from your list of RSS feeds to an email account on an IMAP mail server (thereby providing read/unread synchronising across devices and platforms). With this any old email client that supports IMAP becomes your feed reader. You'd need to export your Feedly OPML, convert it, then script parsing each feed. And you have to rely on cron or something similar for it to run..
2. Use a (self-)hosted [Tiny Tiny RSS](http://tt-rss.org/) server to replace Feedly. You'll need feed reader apps that support tt-rss's APIs. There's apparently an Android client and an Emacs package.

Anyone got thoughts on these or other (possible) alternate solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Did you test [elfeed](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2013/09/04/)? Is not a client for feedly.com, but you can read your RSS feeds within Emacs anyway

Comment: I have, shackra. Thanks for the comment, tho. The issue is/was that I use my phone to read my feeds as well when I'm mobile, so I want/need to sync read articles. elfeed, AFAICT, relies on another mechanism like I listed in the answer to provide that functionality.

Comment: currently elfeed now offers an app for mobile phones, so you can sync it with your phone now.